# Exclude Odata metadata and type from JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, odata

The script below return a JSON from my ODataController

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:37994/odata/EPStructures3/",
      type: "Get",
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(data) 
      {
        //do something.....
      },
      error: function(msg)
      {
        alert(msg);
      }
    });
  }); 
< /script>
```

The JSON :

```
{ "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:37994/odata/$metadata#EPStructures3","value":[{"eps_level":0,"id":2},{"eps_level":1,"id":3}]}
```

I want to exclude the metadata and type so the JSON is returned like this:

```
[{"eps_level":0,"id":2},{"eps_level":1,"id":3}]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

If you add an "Accept: application/json; odata.metadata=none" header to your request you will get as close as you can to what you want.

Comment: Brad, thanks, I tried this. and got {"value":[{"eps_level":0,"id":2},{"eps_level":1,"id":3}]} . I am trying to get [{"eps_level":0,"id":2},{"eps_level":1,"id":3}]

Comment: I don't think what you want us valid OData. The OData specification for message body states what is returned is a JSON object, not a JSON array, which collections being returned as a value property. See http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/errata02/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-errata02-os-complete.html#_Toc403940611 for details.

Comment: Brad, What i am getting is a valid oData. I want to deserialise it into a JSON array [{"eps_level":0,"id":2},{"eps_level":1,"id":3}]. I tried var arr_from_json = JSON.parse(data); but it is not working?